# Use Custom DB for Login in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, sqlite

I am very new to django,  I have an **sqlite3** database file and I want to use a table in it for authentication of my website, It is a very basic html login page, How can I do that?  Also if you can tell me how the built-in login and authenticate work and which DB to they use?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the Django auth documentation? You should do so, and then ask *specific* questions based on anything that's still not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Please read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/ and  http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter14/ for better understanding.

To achieve basic login functionality in Django you can follow below steps.

*Prerequisite:* *You must have valid DB setting in your settings.py*

**1.Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # index page
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.index'),
    # after login user will be redirected to this url
    url(r'^logged_in/$', 'app.views.logged_in'),
    # using default django auth views with custom templates
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'template_name': 'logout.html'}),

)
```

**2. Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.template import RequestContext

# index view (just redirect to login page)
def index(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')

# this view will run after successfull login
@login_required
def logged_in(request):
    return render_to_response('logged_in.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**3. login.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Log in{% endblock %}
{% block extrastyle %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/signin.css" />
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <form action="" class="form-signin" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      <h3 class="form-signin-heading text-center">Please log in</h3>
      {% if form.non_field_errors %}
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ form.non_field_errors|striptags }}
          </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% if not form.username.errors %}
        <input id="id_username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username (admin)" autofocus>
      {% else %}
        <div class="form-group has-error">
          {% for error in form.username.errors %} 
            <label class="control-label" for="id_username">{{ error }}</label>
          {% endfor %}
          <input id="id_username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username (admin)" autofocus>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% if not form.password.errors %}
        <input id="id_password" name="password" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password (admin)" autofocus>
      {% else %}
        <div class="form-group has-error">
          {% for error in form.password.errors %}
            <label class="control-label" for="id_password">{{ error }}</label>
          {% endfor %}
          <input id="id_password" name="password" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password (admin)">
        </div>
      {% endif %}

      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You should complete your answer with the detailed procedure and don't just post external links.

Comment: People should take time to read to have better understanding instead of asking directly without knowing anything.